# Ray RLllib: Export policy for external use

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I have a PPO policy based model that I train with RLLib using the Ray Tune API on some standard gym environments (with no fancy preprocessing). I have model checkpoints saved which I can load from and restore for further training.

Now, I want to export my model for production onto a system that should ideally have no dependencies on Ray or RLLib. Is there a simple way to do this?

I know that there is an interface `export_model` in the `rllib.policy.tf_policy` class, but it doesn't seem particularly easy to use. For instance, after calling `export_model('savedir')` in my training script, and in another context loading via `model = tf.saved_model.load('savedir')`, the resulting `model` object is troublesome (something like `model.signatures['serving_default'](gym_observation)` doesn't work) to feed the correct inputs into for evaluation. I'm ideally looking for a method that would allow for easy out of the box model loading and evaluation on observation objects

Answer (score 0):

Once you have restored from checkpoint with `agent.restore(**checkpoint_path**)`, you can use `agent.export_policy_model(**output_dir**)` to export the model as a `.pb` file and `variables` folder.